# Android phone reboot when run application from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, restart

I am a stranger in android-programming.

My phone reboot once in every three times when I run app from eclipse.

(I always launch application on active devices, not on AVD.)

I googled lots of sites, but there is no solution.

I tried:

1. Switch USB port
2. Project -> Clean (in Eclipse)
3. Delete application and re-install
4. Clean temporary files and registries
5. Re-install Eclipse and Android SDK

However, they are not the solution to this problem.

Here is my info:

- Eclipse ver: ADT (Build v21.1.0-569685)
- Phone OS: ICS (4.0.3)
- Phone model: LG Prada 3.0
- Rooted: Yes
- ROM: not use custom ROM

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: does any log tell anything ?

Comment: No. progress bar stopped and there is no log in logcat.

Comment: How about Factory reset your phone? Before that, you can look into Android's system log ( as you are rooted )